# How to express 3 dimensional motion in Minkowski space?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, spacetime-dimensions, visualization

We can easily visualize Minkowski space diagrams with 2 spatial coordinates but how to express 3 spatial coordinates?

Comment: Is "we can't because it would be a four-dimensional diagram" an acceptable answer to this?

Comment: Seems like it'd be a video, not a single image.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to answer this question by sharing this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zScn3tV9YPU) about Minkowski Space